# How to execute multiple git operations at the same time on VSCode for different repositories

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Each time a commit, push, etc. is executed on VSCode (UI), all options are disabled until the operation completes. This is fine for operations on the same repository, but it shouldn't block the other repositories (on a Multi-root Workspace).

In the picture below, the repository 1 is pushing, but I'm unable to do a commit in the repository 2.

[image]

Is there an option to enable this behavior? If not, is this expected, or should be reported?